# Is it totally fine to use a mutable object as a key in a Dictionary?

Tags: .net, dictionary, key, immutability, gethashcode

Say I have some special class, `WrappedDataTable`, and I want to associate each `WrappedDataTable` with exactly one `DataTable`. Furthermore, I want there to be no more than one `WrappedDataTable` in existence for any given `DataTable`.

A colleague suggested I could cache my `WrappedDataTable` and use a factory method to access one, like this:

```
public static class DataTableWrapper
{
    private Dictionary<DataTable, WrappedDataTable> _wrappedTables;

    static DataTableWrapper()
    {
        _wrappedTables = new Dictionary<DataTable, WrappedDataTable>();
    }

    public static WrappedDataTable Wrap(this DataTable table)
    {
        WrappedDataTable wrappedTable;
        if (!_wrappedTables.TryGetValue(table, out wrappedTable))
            _wrappedTables[table] = wrappedTable = new WrappedDataTable(table);

        return wrappedTable;
    }
}
```

This struck me as very questionable at first, I guess because I've become familiar with the idea that keys in a dictionary should be immutable types. But perhaps this is not necessarily the case? A quick test revealed to me that a `DataTable` appears to maintain a consistent hash code over the course of numerous modifications to its contents; a `Dictionary<DataTable, TValue>` therefore appears to be able to return a correct value for `ContainsKey` consistently.

What I'm wondering is if the base version of `object.GetHashCode` by default will return an unchanging value for every individual object, or if what I'm seeing with `DataTable` is just an illusion?

If the former is true -- and `object.GetHashCode` works just fine -- it seems the "use only immutable types as keys" advice really only applies to scenarios where:

1. You want equality of objects to be about value equality as opposed to reference equality, and/or:
2. You have a custom type with its own `GetHashCode` implementation that is based on the type's members.

Any sages out there care to shed some light on this for me?

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Jon Skeet for answering my question. In other news, I did some digging and think I came up with an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that **does** provide identity comparison after all! Check it out (sorry VB.NET haters, I just had a VB.NET project up so that's what I wrote it in -- translation is trivial):

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class IdentityComparer(Of T As Class)
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of T)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(ByVal x As T, ByVal y As T) As Boolean _
        Implements IEqualityComparer(Of T).Equals

        Return Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(ByVal obj As T) As Integer _
        Implements IEqualityComparer(Of T).GetHashCode

        Return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj)
    End Function
End Class
```

Take a look at this example program:

```
Dim comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of String) = New IdentityComparer(Of String)

Dim x As New String("Hello there")
Dim y As New String("Hello there")

Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(x, y))
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(x))
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(y))
```

Output:

```
False
37121646
45592480
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to return a unique value. It just has to return an unchanging one - and that's what `object.GetHashCode` does.

So long as `DataTable` doesn't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, you've basically got object identity as equality - which means it doesn't matter if the object is mutated.

<strike>Personally I'd like to see an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` which provides identity equality for *any* type, but we can't implement that ourselves - there's no way of finding out  what `GetHashCode` *would* have returned if it hadn't been overridden. (Java has this capability in its standard libraries, but .NET doesn't. Grr.)</strike>

EDIT: Woot - with `object.ReferenceEquals` and `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()`, we can easily implement an `IdentityEqualityComparer<T>`. Yay!

Comment: @Jon: Like a GetHashCodeBase? I admit that I've never done any Java (nodatime was my first foray and I've spent all the time staring at code rather than contributing)

Comment: @Jeff: Some sort of static method somewhere, basically. In Java it's `System.identityHashCode`

Comment: @Jon: Ah, that sounds useful. Would also be useful to be able to get at the original implementations of `ToString` and `Equals` for other purposes.

Comment: @Jon: Hey, take a look at my update! Is that something like what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

I think you understand things fine.  For an object to be stored in a dictionary, any characteristics which would affect its hash value or tests for equality with other objects must be immutable.  Characteristics which would not affect those things need not be immutable.